# k6 on project running on docker

Tags: docker, load-testing, k6

I'm trying to run some tests using k6 on my project running on docker.

I added this to my docker-compose.yml :

```
  k6:
    image: loadimpact/k6:latest
    command: run /test.js
    volumes:
        - ./tests/test.js:/test.js
```

It runs my test when I start the project with `docker-compose up`.

But then the k6 container stops, I want to keep it running so I can do something like `docker exec -it k6_container run test2.js`

How to achieve this ? Is there a cleaner way to run tests ?

I managed to run the tests but I had to install k6 on my PC, since I'm working with a team I want to add it to the dockerized project.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) a new container with an alternate command; for example

```sh
docker-compose run --rm k6 run ./test2.js
```

Containers aren't expensive to start up, and if your test results are written to either the console or the bind-mounted directory, there shouldn't be a difference between reusing the same container or starting a new one.